# How to make UIAppearance proxies apply to programmatically created views?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uilabel, uiappearance

I'm trying to use UIAppearance to create a theme for my app.

Say I want all my `UILabel`'s texts to be orange. I wrote:

```
UILabel.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIView.self]).textColor = .orange
```

But I realized that:

- This worked for every `UILabel` created via Interface Builder.
- This does not work for any `UILabel` created programmatically. They are displayed in black by default

Any idea how I can force programmatically created instances to be orange as well?

PS: I've also tried: `UILabel.appearance().textColor = .green` which is not what I want but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Actually `UILabel.appearance().textColor` should work. When do you call this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching...

Apparently, the fact that UI elements (such as labels) ***created in Interface Builder***  are affected by `.appearance()` settings is not really intentional, and is probably not reliable.

In fact, the documentation seems rather confusing and misleading.

> To support appearance customization, a class must conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol and relevant accessor methods must be marked with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR.

The only classes that adopt `UIAppearance` protocol are

- `UIBarItem`
- `UIView`

and the only classes that adopt `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol are

- `UIPopoverController`
- `UIPresentationController`
- `UIView`
- `UIViewController`

So... best bet is probably to sub-class your labels.

Answer (score 0):

A related answer can be found here : [How to default UILabel Font and Size using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323751/how-to-default-uilabel-font-and-size-using-swift)

From that link:
"UIAppearance only allows you to set properties that are flagged with UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR in the Objective-C header file. Since UILabel has no such properties, it cannot be styled with UIAppearance"

also from: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiappearance

"iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view from the view hierarchy and then put it back."

also from here:[trouble with UIAppearance and UIButton subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18107492/trouble-with-uiappearance-and-uibutton-subclassing)

"The reason it's working this way is because appearance properties are applied when the view is added to a view hierarchy, and nib-defined properties are applied before the view is added to a view hierarchy."

I tried setting the appearance of labels when in instances of a new class of view controller before programatically adding that view controller to the hierarchy, but no luck.